# how to output loss variable of model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I try to use **mnist** classifier to recognize data generated by GAN, but the problem is classifer do not output correct probability vector, it is always same result, like this, by use tf.argmax:

```
> k is  
> [3]  
> k is  
> [3]  
> k is  
> [3]  
> Test finished
```

but mnist classifier trained before,test accur is 99%, here is where I think is not right:

```
 k_index = tf.argmax(classifier_loss, 1)
 for i in range(3):
 img_xs, _ = sess.run([image, label])
 img_x = img_xs/255
 k = k_index.eval(feed_dict={x: img_xs})
 g = np.reshape(img_xs, (28, 28))

 print('k is')
 print(k)
 # print('k is %d' %(k))
 g = Image.fromarray(g, 'L')
 g.show()
 lib.mkdir('./reslut/%d/' %(k))
 g.save('./reslut/%d/%d.jpg' %(k, i))
 print("Test finished")
```

the all code is in [my github](https://github.com/R1994/GAN-mnist-captcha), problem seem happen in `classifier.py`
[code segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CGyH.png)

Comment: The block of code used inside your for loop that calculates `k` does not depend on the incremented loop integer (`i`), hence, gives you the same `k` value for all `i` values.

Comment: Sorry,i can not understand your means,but it is not neccessary to building node strcuture in loop ,maybe? @MehmetKologlu

Comment: I dont know how else i can describe this. Your `k` is the same for every `i` because `k` does not depend on `i`.

Comment: the value of k produce by calculating input:img_xs, in every loop, img_xs changed, the k should be changed,however, it is always same @MehmetKologlu